# How would I encode a list using zlib?

Tags: python, encoding, zlib

How will I be able to encode the values to a txt file, without getting a typeerror. I keep getting "list is not supported by the buffer interface"

```
import zlib
sentence = input("Enter the text you want to compress: ")
listSentence = sentence.split(" ")
d = {}
i = 0
values = []
for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
    if not word in d:
        d[word] = (i+1)
    values += [d[word]]
comv = zlib.compress(values.encode('utf-8'))
with open("listofwords.txt", "wb") as myfile:
myfile.write(comv)
```

This code assigns values to the users input, which is all it does. I need to compress the values into a .txt file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use json to make the list into a string.

i.e.

```
import json
comv = zlib.compress(json.dumps(values))
```

Then you will be able to zlib it.
Of course when you unzip it, you need to use json.loads() to restore it to a list.

Comment: Thank you, I will test this out.